# python pandas - replace character of one column

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace the '@' of Timestamp with a white space with pandas.
Currently my dataframe looks like this:

```
Timestamp                    name                    sex
2020-03-10@15:45:15           x                      y
2020-03-10@16:00:15           x                      y
2020-03-10@17:15:15           x                      y
```

What I want as an output:

```
Timestamp                    name                    sex
2020-03-10 15:45:15           x                      y
2020-03-10 16:00:15           x                      y
2020-03-10 17:15:15           x                      y
```

The replacement of @ to white space works, but for some reason it only returns the Timestamp column and the others are just gone.

Comment: Is timestamp a datetime column or an object column?

Comment: So you want to provide a space instead of the character T?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly replace the string using :

```
df['TimeStamp'] = df['TimeStamp'].str.replace('T',' ')
```

Comment: @minpik I thought you have a dataframe that's why I used dataframe. Do you need to perform it on the list? I see that you have changed it to content['Timestamp'] which is not a dataframe but a list